# Get diagnoses from Pepper QiSDK

Tags: pepper

In Naoqi 2.5, one can subscribe and use ALNotificationManager to obtain diagnoses such as some of my motors are too hot in my xx.
How can we get such diagnoses using QiSDK? We want to operate Pepper remotely and need this information to handle timely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`ALDiagnosis`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/diagnosis/aldiagnosis-api.html?highlight=aldiagnosis), and more precisely [getDignosisStatus](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/diagnosis/aldiagnosis-api.html?highlight=aldiagnosis#ALDiagnosisProxy::getDiagnosisStatus).

It returns serializable data describing the detected issues.